# Remove Tap event until fadeOut ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [this](http://aarongloege.github.io/jquery.tap/) Jquery Tap Plugin to generate `tap` event. What i'm trying to achieve is to remove the clicks or taps from divs or links until it completes fading out. Although the `click` event binds and unbinds while the `tap` isn't. Appreciate any help on this.

binding click:

```
$(".btns li a").bind("click",true);
```

unbinding click:

```
$(".btns li a").unbind("click",true);
```

This is not working when `click` is replaced with `tap`

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AJGQn/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Hey, Tap is for Touch devices, did you try it on touch device?

Comment: no I haven't tested it on a touch device.... I was just testing whether the `tap` event can be unregistered